# Parsing xml on android emulator is very slow compared to real device (only while debugging)

Tags: java, android, xml-parsing, android-emulator

It is only happens when debugging application (I use IntelliJ 12 Ultimate) otherwise it works fast both on emulator and device.

This code (called in `AsyncTask` class, in `doInBackground` method )

`rss` = String with ~40k chars

```
DocumentBuilderFactory dbf = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
DocumentBuilder db = dbf.newDocumentBuilder();
StringReader reader = new StringReader(rss);            
InputSource is = new InputSource(reader);            
Document doc = db.parse(is); //here it hangs
```

Takes over minute on Android Emulator with settings:
 
**API:** lvl 15
**CPU/ABI:** ARM(armsabi-v7a)
**Sd Card:** 100 MiB
**Snapshot:** Enabled
**Skin:** Built-in WVGA800
**Hardware:**

- **Abstracted LCD density:** 240
- **Max VM application heap size:** 48
- **Device ram size:** 1024

On my **HTC One X** device:
**CPU quad-core:** 1,5 GHz
**Memory:** 16GB
**RAM:** 1GB

```
dalvik.vm.heapsize=128m
dalvik.vm.heapgrowthlimit=64m
```

it works instantly

Generally I'm understanding that emulator is slower - specially when running on AMD CPU but still I want to make sure if it is a problem of emulator or my parsing approach is somehow inappropriate.

Update:
As I marked on the beginning - it happens only when debugging so looks more like emulator problem...

Comment: The emulator runs slower than real devices.  We'd only be able to tell you whether or not there's a problem with your parsing approach if you shared the parsing approach with us...

Comment: Ouch! Added missing lines - question updated - thx